# How can I Fix this SQL Syntax error 1064, Where It says to look at the MySQL server version for the right syntax to use?

Tags: python, mysql, django

ERROR :
`django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'' at line 1")`

Code:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'REDACTED',
        'USER': 'REDACTED',
        'PASSWORD': 'REDACTED',
        'HOST': 'REDACTED',
        'PORT': 'REDACTED',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode:'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        }
    }
}
```

MySQL Version = mysqlclient : 1.4.6
Server version: 5.7.31 - Gentoo Linux mysql-5.7.31
Protocol version: 10

Help is very appreciated

Comment: The examples I've seen for that command use an equal sign, not a colon.  `SET sql_mode = 'some mode'`

Comment: First stop: [The documentation on `SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-statement.html).

Comment: Hey, that's what the error said to do. You're so clever @tadman :-) (it was 5.7 though)

Comment: @danblack "Check the manual" is always good advice. The syntax hasn't changed since at least MySQL 3 as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix it by changing my Database Code to :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'prismgaming_admin',
        'USER': 'prismgaming',
        'PASSWORD': 'WEATid4dLe',
        'HOST': 'prismgaming.xyz',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        },
    }
}
```